# socket code in Windows Forms c++

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, sockets, c++-cli

I have to integrate my project (which uses Windows Forms for a simple UI) with a third party program, which runs in server mode, so I need a socket. Below is the relevant code:

Entry point:

```
 #include "UserInterface1.h"
 #include "PanguConnection.h"


 using namespace std;
 using namespace client;


 int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, 
 HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
 {  
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::Run(gcnew UserInterface1()); 

    return 0;
 }
```

Socket code:

```
#ifndef PANGUCONNECTION_H_INCLUDED
 #define PANGUCONNECTION_H_INCLUDED

 #include "socket_stuff.h" 
 #include "pan_protocol_lib.h"

 //#define SERVER_NAME  "192.0.0.10"
 const int SERVER_PORT = 10363;

 class PanguConnection    
 {
 private:
    long addr;  
    SOCKET sock;
    unsigned long saddr_len;
    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    char SERVER_NAME [10];

 public:
    PanguConnection();
    void Connection();
    unsigned long hostid_to_address(char *s);   
    void Terminate ();
    int simple_tests(SOCKET sock);
    int general_tests(SOCKET);
    int elevation_test(SOCKET);
    int lookup_test(SOCKET);
    int scan_test(SOCKET);
    int get_and_save_image(SOCKET sock, char *fname);   
 };

 #endif // PANGUCONNECTION_H_INCLUDED

 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <cmath>

 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 #include "PanguConnection.h"

 #include "socket_stuff.h" 
 #include "pan_protocol_lib.h"

 using namespace std;

 PanguConnection::PanguConnection() 
 {
        SERVER_NAME [0] = 'l';
        SERVER_NAME [1] = 'o';
        SERVER_NAME [2] = 'c';
        SERVER_NAME [3] = 'a';
        SERVER_NAME [4] = 'l';
        SERVER_NAME [5] = 'h';
        SERVER_NAME [6] = 'o';
        SERVER_NAME [7] = 's';
        SERVER_NAME [8] = 't';      

 #ifdef _WIN32
    WSAData wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &wsaData)){}

 #endif

        /* First get the numeric IP address of the server */
        addr = hostid_to_address((char *)SERVER_NAME);

        /* Create a communications TCP/IP socket */
        sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);     

        /* Connect the socket to the remote server */
        saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = addr;
        saddr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
        saddr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in); 

        int res = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, saddr_len);  

        /* Start the PANGU network communications protocol */
        pan_protocol_start(sock);

        int res1 = simple_tests(sock);
        int res2 = general_tests(sock);
        int res3 = elevation_test(sock);
    int res4 =  lookup_test(sock);
    int res5 = scan_test(sock);
    }

    unsigned long PanguConnection::hostid_to_address(char *s)
    {
        struct hostent *host;

        /* Assume we have a dotted IP address ... */
        long result = inet_addr(s);
        if (result != (long)INADDR_NONE) return result;

        /* That failed so assume DNS will resolve it. */
        host = gethostbyname(s);
        return host ? *((long *)host->h_addr_list[0]) : INADDR_NONE;
 }


 int PanguConnection::simple_tests(SOCKET sock)
 {
    int i, status;
    float x, y, z, yaw, pitch, roll;
    char fname[1024];

    /* Initialise the camera position */
    x = 192.257f, y = 192.257f, z = 126.785f;
    yaw = 135.0f, pitch = -25.0f, roll = 0.0f;

    /* Define the field of view we want to use */
    pan_protocol_set_field_of_view(sock, 30.0);

    /* Instruct the viewer to use this position */
    pan_protocol_set_viewpoint_by_angle(sock, x, y, z, yaw, pitch, roll);

    /* Fly towards the model with constant attitude */
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        /* Set the new position */
        x -= 1.9f, y -= 1.9f, z -= 1.2f;
        pan_protocol_set_viewpoint_by_angle(sock, x, y, z, yaw, pitch, roll);

        /* Get this image */

        status = get_and_save_image(sock, fname);
        if (status) return status;
    }
```

...other functions to test the connection are omitted

User interface code (the idea is that clicking the button the connection starts and some images are retrieved from the third party program which runs in server mode):

```
#pragma once

 #define _WINSOCKAPI_    // stops windows.h including winsock.h
 #include <winsock2.h>
 #include <windows.h>

 #include "PanguConnection.h"


 namespace client {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::IO;


    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for UserInterface1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class UserInterface1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        UserInterface1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~UserInterface1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    protected: 

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

 #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->pictureBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^
(this->pictureBox1))->BeginInit();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this->pictureBox1->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ButtonFace;
            this->pictureBox1->BorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::BorderStyle::Fixed3D;
            this->pictureBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(52, 55);
            this->pictureBox1->Name = L"pictureBox1";
            this->pictureBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(555, 476);
            this->pictureBox1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->pictureBox1->TabStop = false;
            this->pictureBox1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &UserInterface1::pictureBox1_Click);
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(657, 55);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(104, 61);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->button1->Text = L"button1";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &UserInterface1::button1_Click);
            // 
            // UserInterface1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(8, 16);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ActiveCaptionText;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(802, 596);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox1);
            this->Name = L"UserInterface1";
            this->Text = L"UserInterface1";
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  (this->pictureBox1))->EndInit();
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
 #pragma endregion

    private: System::Void pictureBox1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             }

    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                PanguConnection PC;
             }
    };
 }
```

The complier doesn't complain about anything, but the program does not work as it should. The socket simply doesn't work and nothing happens when the button is clicked.
Any idea? I'd really appreciate any input.

ok I have tried to implement it as you suggested @Mgetz, but there still seem to be a problem:

```
#pragma once

using namespace System::Net::Sockets;
using namespace System;

ref class PanguConnect
{
private:
   TcpClient ^mTcpClient; 

public:
    PanguConnect(void);
    void Connection(System::String^ server, Int32 port);  
    void CloseConnection ();
}; 

#include "PanguConnect.h"
using namespace System::Net::Sockets;
using namespace System;

PanguConnect::PanguConnect(void)
{
}

void PanguConnect::Connection(System::String^ server, Int32 port)
    {           
        mTcpClient = gcnew TcpClient(server, port);

    }

void PanguConnect::CloseConnection ()
{
    mTcpClient->Close();
}
```

User interface part:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                PanguConnect PC;
                 try{                
                    PC.Connection("localhost",10363);
                    }

                catch(Exception ^e)
                {
                    MessageBox::Show(e->Message);
                }


                try
                {
                    PC.CloseConnection ();
                }

                catch(Exception ^e)
                {
                    MessageBox::Show(e->Message);
                }
             }
```

The error I get is: No connection made because the target machine actively refused it: 127.0.0.1:10363. Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
:(

Comment: The .Net framework contains access to [sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1), why not just use that?

Comment: yes I thought about that. I got the code for the socket from the third party program, though (but it was not developed to be used in Windows Forms), so I thought i'd try to implement that. I think i'll do as you say though. Thanks for the input

Comment: Was the application created as a winforms project? If so it is probably set to be pure CLR.

Comment: the original third party application was created in native C/C++. This is the main problem I think. I am not too familiar myself with the original code

Comment: Because `PanguConnect` is a `ref` object you'll need to do a `gcnew PanguConnect();` before it will exist. Also verify that you can connect to the server via telnet or the like. If the server is refusing connections then it definitely won't work.

Comment: ok that was very dumb of me. Sorry and thanks for the very prompt feedback and for taking the time to look into this. the problem of the pangu program crashing and the refused connection persists though. I am going to try and fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is actually implemented directly in the .NET framework there is no need to use winsock directly and in-fact it is more dangerous to do so.

```
using namespace System::Net::Sockets;

public ref class PanguConnection
{
    private:
    System::Net:Sockets::TcpClient mTcpClient;

    public:
    PanguConnection(System::String^ server, Int32 port)
    {
        this->mTcpClient = gcnew System::Net::Sockets::TcpClient(server, port);
    }
}
```

Note I noticed you were using TCP for this so [`System::Net::Sockets::TcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) should work

Comment: for some reason it voted your answer down instead of up - dangit